# SQL - CASE statement to filter the query

Tags: sql-server-2014

Hi all I am having stored procedure where I am selecting the same columns, my query is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_DATA
    @in_filter_column1 NVARCHAR(6),
    @in_filter_column2 NVARCHAR(50),
    @in_flag BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    IF @in_flag = 0
        SELECT      t1.COLUMN1, t1.COLUM2, t2.COLUMN3
        FROM        table1 t1
        INNER JOIN  table2 t2
        ON          t1.column1 = t2.column1
        WHERE       t1.column1 = @in_filter_column1
    ELSE
        SELECT      t1.COLUMN1, t1.COLUM2, t2.COLUMN3
        FROM        table1 t1
        INNER JOIN  table2 t2
        ON          t1.column1 = t2.column1
        INNER JOIN  table3 t3
        ON          t3.column1 = t2.column1
        WHERE       t3.column1 = @in_filter_column2
END
```

so here instead of writing the same select condition I would like to simply using switch case or other alternative way. Is it possible

One way I know is like this I am trying for any other

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_DATA
        @in_filter_column1 NVARCHAR(6),
        @in_filter_column2 NVARCHAR(50),
        @in_flag BIT = 0
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql_query = ' SELECT       t1.COLUMN1, t1.COLUM2, t2.COLUMN3
            FROM        table1 t1
            INNER JOIN  table2 t2
            ON          t1.column1 = t2.column1'

        IF @in_flag = 0
        SET @sql_query = @sql_query + ' WHERE t1.column1 = ''' + @in_filter_column1 +''''
        ELSE
            SET @sql_query = @sql_query + ' INNER JOIN  table2 t3
                            ON      t3.column1 = t1.column1 WHERE t3.column1 = ''' + @in_filter_column2 +''''
        END
```

Comment: Is it safe and possible to always join table3, even if @in_flag is 0?

Comment: No I need to join as per the condition